# can use defined( 'ABSPATH' ) in WordPress theme?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

Can this **constant** be used to prevent files from being called directly in **wordpress themes**? Is there a need for this? Is there an alternative solution?

Comment: You can write `defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;` in every theme file to prevent direct access to files.

Comment: From the reviews I've done, most of the themes and popular themes don't use this technique, is it necessary to do this in the theme?

Comment: I won't say it's necessary, and it's not usually needed but in some cases, you might need it, You can get more details on this topic [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/63004/218789), I personally, make a check in all the template parts, classes, functions files, event on `functions.php` it doesn't break anything so why not make a security check.